# how to run a controller function in modal in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, modal-dialog, laravel-5.3

what I am trying to do is to run a controller delete function in a modal and it's at the end of the loop when I try to use that delete function it gets the last id and delete that instead, I want it t get the current id on which the function was called. what should I be doing?? I cant put the code of the model in CSS file cause it disturbs the other styling so the script code should be in the blade view

```
@section('content')
@if($promotions)
    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box overflowhidden">
                <div class="box-body datatablelist">
   <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sr No</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach ($promotions as $promotion)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @if(!empty($promotion->id))
                                        {{$promotion->id}}
                                    @else
                                        N/A
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                            <li>
     <a href="#" class="myBtn" id="myBtn"onclick="showDeleteModal(this.id)">
       <i class="fa fa-trash-o"   aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                          </ul>
                                    </div>


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>


            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->

    <!-- page script -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Are you sure you wants to delete the promotion</p>
   {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','action'=>
    ['PromotionController@destroy',$promotion->id]]) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"> Delete</i>', ['type' => 
    'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger pull-right btn-
   sm','style'=>'margin-bottom:1em'] )  }}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endif
```

and here is the script code

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Are you sure you wants to delete the promotion</p>
            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','action'=>
     ['PromotionController@destroy',$promotion->id]]) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
     {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash-o"> Delete</i>', ['type' => 
   'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger pull-right btn-sm','style'=>'margin-
   bottom:1em'] )  }}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endif
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#example1').DataTable({

                "ordering": false,

            });
        });

    </script>
<script>
    function showDeleteModal(id){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");


    }
</script>
```

and here is the controller function

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $promotion = Promotion::findOrFail($id);
        $promotion->delete($id);
        return redirect('admin/promotion');

    }
```

Comment: where is your controller function?

Comment: Is it a single question or two different Questions ?

Comment: @PHPWorm... on a click to delete function i want to show a modal which is working fine and on that modal i wants to call delete function through a button

Comment: You are using $promotion->id after foreach ends and that is why it always stores last ID and you are using it in form action you need to make it dynamic. You can do this using Jquery. Also there is an error in showDeleteModal(this.id) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$promotion->id` in modal after `foreach` ends and that is why it always stores `last ID` and you are using it in `form` `action` you need to make it dynamic. You can do this using `Jquery`. Also there is an error in `showDeleteModal(this.id)` too

You need to update your `showDeleteModal(this.id)` function

```
function showDeleteModal(id){
   var form = $("#myModal").find('form');
   var url = form.attr('action');
   url = url.split('/');
   url[url.length - 1] = id;
   url = url.join('/'); 
   form.attr('action',url);
   $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
}
```

And

```
<a href="#" class="myBtn" id="myBtn"onclick="showDeleteModal(this.id)">
```

TO

```
<a href="#" class="myBtn" id="myBtn"onclick="showDeleteModal({{$promotion->id}})">
```

Comment: My pleasure Mate  :)